# Create startup script for Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, boot

for my new server I need a startup script that does the following things:
- Execute some executables, but under their own username for security purposes.
- Run a number of iptable commands since the whole save-iptables-thingy doesn't seem to work.

Any advise? It seems complicated!

Answer (score 0):

Plenty of ways described in [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up). Using a `@reboot` line in the crontab has  a lot of appeal, especially since IIRC the Ubuntu variant of crontab also allows to specify which id runs the command.

Since you are on Ubuntu you can use UFW (Uncomplicated FireWall). IPTables for mere humans :)

Answer (score 0):

`/etc/rc.local` still works. It is the very last thing run in the boot process, so all network, etc. should be up and everything should be working/up and running.

I'd write a small script for each task, with output redirected to a log file.  Call them from `/etc/rc.local` using `su someuser -c /path/to/script`.

And as xenoid says in his answer, use `ufw` for your iptables needs, it actually does have a working save/restore :)